# Post comment to other website from my site using a form

Tags: post, dns, comments

I want to post some data to other web page from my page using a pseudo-form. If user post something using the form of my page as a result this will be posted to a target page of other domain which exist to a different server.
Say my site is *http:// abcd .com* and the target site is *http:// xyz .com*
If user post a comment using my form this will be posted to xyz.com.
First I tried as followed:-

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://xyz.com/cmnt_next.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{'cmntid':100,'user':'guest','cmnt':'Hello world'},
    success:function(result){
        alert("res: "+result);
    }
});
```

Finally I found that **ajax** dose not send request to external domain. I don't have any other Idea to do it. I want to know what is the legal way to do it, with their permission. What do I need to know to get access to post, also if needs to 'Login' to the target site before posting through my webpage. I need any tips & solution to do this thing.
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

The "legal" way to do this would be to use an API that the site provides for you to log in and/or make posts to xyz.com.  If they don't, then they probably don't want you to do this, and then you probably shouldn't be doing it.